# Mamp Pro Apache won't start on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, macos-catalina, mamp-pro

Apache won't start anymore.

I tried most solutions on the internet. Nothing is working.
In `apache_error.log` I get:

```
[Fri Dec 27 20:33:10 2019] [alert] Child 5905 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Fri Dec 27 20:33:10 2019] [alert] (22)Invalid argument: getpwuid: couldn't determine user name from uid 4294967295, you probably need to modify the User directive
[Fri Dec 27 20:33:10 2019] [alert] (22)Invalid argument: getpwuid: couldn't determine user name from uid 4294967295, you probably need to modify the User directive
[Fri Dec 27 20:33:10 2019] [alert] (22)Invalid argument: getpwuid: couldn't determine user name from uid 4294967295, you probably need to modify the User directive
```

Now this [dude/dudette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733536/apache-in-mamp-pro-4-has-stopped-working-refuses-to-start) here says to reset the default

But that doesn't help.

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer myself.

Reset the templates is not enough.

> File > Edit Template > Revert all Templates to default settings…

And then also:

> File > Factory Setting > Setting 1

Then I set the ports back to 80… via the standard ports button.

Now it works

Comment: For me that option "Revert all..." is greyed out :(

Comment: Ufff... was not able to start my mamp out of nothing.I don't get why the ports suddenly changed but setting them back to default (80) apache started again. Thanks fo sharing!

Answer (score 1):

MAMP Pro 6 wants the document root for each host to be outside of /Applications/MAMP.  I deleted all my old hosts, moved the root directories to /Users/me/Sites, and added new hosts with the new document roots.  Then one last step seemed to be the final trick:

File > Reset Apache Modules

Fingers crossed.  No other suggestions in other threads helped.  Didn't get any errors in the apache log file.

Comment: I had this problem even though none of my hosts were in the /Applications/MAMP directory. The magic Reset Apache Modules totally fix it for me, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me the following worked:

- go to '~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO`
- delete the file `httpd.conf`

After restarting Mamp, the file gets regenerated and apache runs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the option set server ports to 80, 81, 443, 7443, 3306 and 11211 in ports & user worked for me - mamp pro 6.3.2